# MediaWiki most brute force backup?

Tags: git, mediawiki, wiki

I brought up MediaWiki using [Bintami](http://bitnami.com/stack/mediawiki) stack. Now am trying to figure out the most brute force way to back up the the wiki and have ability to bring it up on another server as well. I have looked over the [manual](http://www.mediawiki.org/wiki/Manual:Backing_up_a_wiki#Scripts) briefly but glancing over it seems like there will be things that don't go according to plan and will take time to get working properly.

Pretty much I am toying with the idea of using Git to keep the files used under source control. I was wondering whether anyone has tried using source control to backup wiki files without doing any SQL dumps and whether its known which folders are required for this to work if its even suppose to work.

Comment: all of the wiki content is usually in the SQL DB, so without a DB backup, you will lose all the important stuff -- unless you've selected a different storage (dunno which ones mediawiki currently supports)

Comment: also, if you want to use git for working with a wiki, you might want to take a look at https://github.com/gollum/gollum

Answer (score 0):

If you want simple backups, you can install MW using SQLite instead of MySQL, then you just need to copy one file (preferrably with `php maintenance/sqlite.php --backup-to=/some/dir`), however I personally don't see any problems with backing up MySQL either - it's one shell command as well.

Comment: what is the command?

Comment: @axrwkr: http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/mysqldump.html